# How do you parse input from a text file in JAVA?

Tags: java, parseint, numberformatexception

I tried to parse the String from my input.txt file, but I get the NumberFormatException thrown every time. I've added all the code that I have so far.
I have tried .trim as well. I am very new to text files in Java; therefore, I have no idea what is wrong here. However, any bit of help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab5_Exceptions_Redo extends Exception {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String file = "inputt.txt";
        String file1 = "outputt.txt";
        String file2 = "errorr.txt";

        PrintWriter errorr = new PrintWriter(file2);

        PrintWriter inputt = new PrintWriter(file);
        inputt.println(15951);
        // int whatever = Integer.parseInt(file);
        // System.out.print(whatever);
        inputt.close();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String number = scan.nextLine();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(number.trim());
        System.out.printf("%d", num);

        PrintWriter outputt = new PrintWriter(file1);
        outputt.println(num);
        outputt.close();
        // inputt.close();

        scan.close();
        // System.out.printf("%d", num);

        try {

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            errorr.println("There was an input mismatch error.");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            errorr.println("There is no such element.");
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            errorr.println("An unsupported operation occured.");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        errorr.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the issue?. What  do you see when you try to print `num`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a mistake. In `Scanner` constructor you should pass `File` object not `String` object. Since you are passing string "inputt.txt" its trying to parse this string and as a result you are getting NFE.
Try this

`Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(file));`

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting the whitespaces along with the input while doing `nextLine()`. Use `trim()` function to get rid of any whitespaces.

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(number.trim());
```

Alternatively, you can try using `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()`.

Here is the JAVA Doc of `parseInt()`:

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

Comment: I tried the .trim, and unfortunately it does not work \: . I am very new to creating text files in Java, and that is why I am so confused as to why it will not parse the integer from the input text file.

Comment: This is not the actual root cause